# Can't update Array of objects

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

I'm trying to create an array of objects using simple-schema. In this example, a person has a careerHistory object that is filled with individual positions. I can't figure out how to insert and update the array of objects. It just errors. The only way I can get it to work is to be explicit, eg. `'careerHistory.position.1.company'`.

I'm using:

- meteor
- simple-schema
- reactjs
- collection2-core

Path: `mongodb`

```
const ProfileCandidateSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  userId: {
    type: String,
    regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id
  },
  careerHistory: { type: Array, optional: true },
  'careerHistory.position': { type: Object, optional: true },
  'careerHistory.position.$': { type: Object, optional: true },
  'careerHistory.position.$.company': { type: String, optional: true },
  'careerHistory.position.$.title': { type: String, optional: true }
});
```

Path: `updateForm.js`

```
ProfileCandidate.update(id, { $set: {
    'careerHistory.position.company': this.state['position.company'],
    'careerHistory.position.title': this.state['position.title'],
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to push object to array do

```
ProfileCandidate.update(id, 
  { $push: { careerHistory: { position: {
    'company': this.state['position.company'],
    'title': this.state['position.title'],
  }}}
});
```

if you want to update particular object

```
ProfileCandidate.update({ _id: id, 'careerHistory.position.company': this.state['position.company'] }, { $set: {
    'careerHistory.position.$.title': this.state['position.title'],
  }
});
```

see `$` in set

Comment: When I try and run the `push object` within a method I get an error `Exception while invoking method 'careerHistory.update' Error: After filtering out keys not in the schema, your modifier is now empty`